# i<c-e> and i<c-y> copy to end of line

Tags: insert-mode

In insert mode `<c-e>` and `<c-y>` copy a character at a time from the above line.

I generally use these when working with aligned bits of text inside a program and want to copy to the end of the line more often than anything else.

Is there a way to do this?

So far I've been using:

```
inoremap <c-e> <esc>lj"py$hk"pp`[
inoremap <c-y> <esc>lk"py$hj"pp`[
```

and a slightly better version to that doesn’t stop executing at the `h` when running at the 0th column.

```
inoremap <c-e> <c-o>:stopinsert<cr>j"py$kv"pp`[
inoremap <c-y> <c-o>:stopinsert<cr>k"py$jv"pp`[
```

But I'm not thrilled with either of those bindings since it clobbers a named register, seems dependent on `set virtualedit`.

Is there a simpler/more elegant way to copy the trailing portion of the above line?

Comment: What's the "strange behavior"? And if you don't want to use a named register why not something like `inoremap <c-e> <c-o>:norm! jly$kp`[<CR>`

Comment: Strange behavior is the command stops as soon as `h` fails. Ah, I also don’t want to clobber the default register either.  I was hoping that this configuration desideratum would be common enough to have a setting or plugin or something similar.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make use of Vim's full functionality (e.g. unnamed register, virtual edit)? Seems kind of...well...masochistic. ;)

Comment: Oh, I use virtualedit always, but other people might not. I’m hoping for a way of rebinding `^E` and `^Y` that isn’t dependent on optional configuration settings and isn’t disruptive to anyone’s workflow, should they choose to override the default behavior.

Comment: `yyp` and edit, or `<C-x><C-l>` if the lines are exactly the same

Comment: If you want to avoid registers perhaps some vimscript...e.g. for  `<c-e>` :  `let b:col = getcurpos()[2] | call setline(".", strcharpart(getline("."), 0, b:col) . strcharpart(getline(getcurpos()[1] + 1), b:col))` . for `<c-y>` change "+ 1" to "- 1".  (I'm ignoring any exit/entry from/to Insert mode for simplicity's sake.)